# Is there a good way to get JAVA_HOME real path with Ansible?

Tags: java, ansible

Use Ansible to install Java as

```
- name: Install Java
  yum:
  ┆ name:
  ┆ ┆ - java-1.8.0-openjdk
  ┆ state: present
```

Then set JAVA_HOME environment variable in `~/.bash_profile`

```
- name: Update .bash_profile
  copy:
  ┆ src: bash_profile
  ┆ dest: /home/user/.bash_profile
  ┆ owner: user
```

bash_profile as

```
...
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre
```

But after a long time, when run the playbook to install Java again, its version maybe upgraded.
So the real path maybe change to other folder. Can't use Java correctly.

From this [article](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-java-8-on-centos-7/), we can find this method can get Java's path

```
update-alternatives --config java
Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)</code?
```

Is it possible to find it from Ansible playbook?

Comment: What about using `$JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: @dan1st I need to set `JAVA_HOME` to `bash_profile` file. Then source it. Where do you mean to use it?

Comment: Have you tried using/looking for Galaxy that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following task to fetch the JAVA_HOME at runtime.

```
- name: "Fetch JAVA_HOME"
  shell: dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which javac)))
  register: java_home
```

Below URL provided more way of finding `JAVA_HOME`:

Eg:

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version 2>&1 |grep -oP 'java.home =\s\K.*'
```

More read: [Original artical](https://www.baeldung.com/find-java-home)